# Problem with copying local data onto HDFS on a Hadoop cluster using Amazon EC2/ S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hadoop, cloud, hdfs

I have setup a Hadoop cluster containing 5 nodes on Amazon EC2. Now, when i login into the Master node and submit the following command

```
bin/hadoop jar <program>.jar <arg1> <arg2> <path/to/input/file/on/S3>
```

It throws the following errors (not at the same time.) The first error is thrown when i don't replace the slashes with '%2F' and the second is thrown when i replace them with '%2F':

```
1) Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI S3://<ID>:<SECRETKEY>@<BUCKET>/<path-to-inputfile>
2) org.apache.hadoop.fs.S3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 PUT failed for '/' XML Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. check your key and signing method.
```

Note:

1)when i submitted jps to see what tasks were running on the Master, it just showed

```
1116 NameNode
1699 Jps
1180 JobTracker
```

leaving DataNode and TaskTracker.

2)My Secret key contains two '/' (forward slashes). And i replace them with '%2F' in the S3 URI.

PS: The program runs fine on EC2 when run on a single node. Its only when i launch a cluster, i run into issues related to copying data to/from S3 from/to HDFS. And, what does distcp do? Do i need to distribute the data even after i copy the data from S3 to HDFS?(I thought, HDFS took care of that internally)

IF you could direct me to a link that explains running Map/reduce programs on a hadoop cluster using Amazon EC2/S3. That would be great.

Regards,

Deepak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also you [Apache Whirr](http://incubator.apache.org/whirr/index.html) for this workflow. Check the [Quick Start Guide](http://incubator.apache.org/whirr/quick-start-guide.html) and the [5 minutes guide](http://incubator.apache.org/whirr/whirr-in-5-minutes.html) for more info.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the committers.

Answer (score 21):

You probably want to use s3n:// urls, not s3:// urls. s3n:// means "A regular file, readable from the outside world, at this S3 url".  s3:// refers to an HDFS file system mapped into an S3 bucket.

To avoid the URL escaping issue for the access key (and to make life much easier), put them into the `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>0123458712355</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>hi/momasgasfglskfghaslkfjg</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>0123458712355</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>hi/momasgasfglskfghaslkfjg</value>
</property>
```

There was at one point an outstanding issue with secret keys that had a slash -- the URL was decoded in some contexts but not in others. I don't know if it's been fixed, but I do know that with the keys in the .conf this goes away.

Other quickies:

- You can most quickly debug your problem using the hadoop filesystem commands, which work just fine on s3n:// (and s3://) urls. Try `hadoop fs -cp s3n://myhappybucket/` or `hadoop fs -cp s3n://myhappybucket/happyfile.txt /tmp/dest1` and even `hadoop fs -cp /tmp/some_hdfs_file s3n://myhappybucket/will_be_put_into_s3`
- The `distcp` command runs a mapper-only command to copy a tree from there to here. Use it if you want to copy a very large number of files to the HDFS. (For everyday use, `hadoop fs -cp src dest` works just fine).
- You don't have to move the data to the HDFS if you don't want.  You can pull all the source data straight from s3, do all further manipulations targeting either the HDFS or S3 as you see fit.
- Hadoop can become confused if there is a file s3n://myhappybucket/foo/bar and a "directory" (many files with keys s3n://myhappybucket/foo/bar/something). Some old versions of the s3sync command would leave just such 38-byte turds in the S3 tree.
- If you start seeing `SocketTimeoutException`'s, [apply the patch for HADOOP-6254](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6254). We were, and we did, and they went away.

Comment: AS of 5/1/2014 this answer is still quite relevant and VERY helpful.  Mods, I'm going to add a few flags in this next sentence to help future searchers:  If you are having trouble with CDH5 or CDH4 and distcp, I highly recommend editing your core-site.xml as indicated above.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Amazon Elastic MapReduce. It removes the need for configuring the hadoop nodes, and you can just access objects in your s3 account in the way you expect.

Comment: @Deepak try this out, there is a lot of information here. https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticmapreduce/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key>
```

e.g.

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key> -<subsubcommand> <args>
```

or

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key> -<subsubcommand> <args>
```