# Unable to copy NCDC Data from Amazon AWS to Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am trying to copy the NCDC Data from Amazon S3 to my local hadoop cluster by using following command.

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId='ABC' -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey='XYZ' s3n://hadoopbook/ncdc/all input/ncdc/all
```

And getting error which is given below :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Secret Access Key must be specified as           the password of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey property
```

Gone through the following question but of no big help.

[Problem with Copying Local Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009792/problem-with-copying-local-data-onto-hdfs-on-a-hadoop-cluster-using-amazon-ec2)

Any hint about how to solve the problem . Detailed answer will be very appreciated for better understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

Excerpt from [AmazonS3 Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20161030154547/wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3#Running_bulk_copies_in_and_out_of_S3)

> Here is an example copying a nutch segment named 0070206153839-1998 at
> /user/nutch in hdfs to an S3 bucket named 'nutch' (Let the S3
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID be 123 and the S3 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET be 456):
>
> % ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop distcp
> hdfs://domU-12-31-33-00-02-DF:9001/user/nutch/0070206153839-1998
> s3://123:456@nutch/

In you case, it should be something like this:

```
hadoop distcp s3n://ABC:XYZ@hadoopbook/ncdc/all hdfs://IPaddress:port/input/ncdc/all
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the aws id and password in the core-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
<value>xxxxxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>xxxxxxxxx</value>
</property>
```

and restart your cluster