# Issues creating a Hive table backed by Avro files in Amazon S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I've been trying to create a Hive table backed by Avro files in S3. Initially, I thought this might be relatively simple to do, but I ran into the following error.

Here's the create table command:

```
set fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=ACCESS_KEY_ID;
set fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
use some_database;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE experiment_with_s3_backed_data
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        'avro.schema.literal'='{
        "namespace": "",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "SomeAvroSchema",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "someVariable","type":"string"}
        ]
}')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://MY_BUCKET/some/data/'
;
```

And here's the error I get:

```
AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
```

I tried using both `s3` and `s3n` URLs and parameters, with the same result. I noticed related questions, which recommend adding the keys to `core-site.xml`, but I can't do this for two reasons:

1. I can't change the Hadoop configuration, due to access restrictions.
2. I might have different tables with different access privileges to S3, so I'm generally interested in providing users with the ability to load their S3 data into Hive tables.

See [Problem with copying local data onto HDFS on a Hadoop cluster using Amazon EC2/ S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009792/problem-with-copying-local-data-onto-hdfs-on-a-hadoop-cluster-using-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for the S3 key settings by adding the keys directly to the S3 URL like so:

```
s3n://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@MY_BUCKET/some/data/'
```

The resulting create table statement then looks like this:

```
use some_database;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE experiment_with_s3_backed_data
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
        "namespace": "",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "SomeAvroSchema",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "someVariable","type":"string"}
        ]
}')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3n://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@MY_BUCKET/some/data/'
;
```